# Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for wp_enqueue_style

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm getting the following error: Warning: filemtime(): stat failed

This is my code:

```
wp_enqueue_style(
    '_themename-stylesheet',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/assets/css/main.css',
    [],
    filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/dist/assets/css/main.css'),
    'all'
);
```

I've also tried using get_stylesheet_directory, but I'm getting the same error.
Echoing get_template_directory() . '/dist/assets/css/main.css' seems to return the right path.

I'm creating a WordPress theme locally on my Mac. Can I even use filemtime in a local environment?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem myself. A scss error was blocking my gulp build and the css file in the dist folder did not exist.